# How to change the URL pattern from /index.jsp to /test/index.jsp by configuring web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have jsp file named `index.jsp` in root folder (webcontent), till now I simply used to access the page using the following URL:

> http://localhost:8080/Sample/index.jsp

Where Sample is the project name.

Now I was asked to change the URL pattern to the following without changing the location of index.jsp file (i.e. still the index.jsp be under webcontent folder):

> http://localhost:8080/Sample/test/index.jsp

How to achieve this by configuring the web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by the following way

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/index.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In `<servlet>` instead of mapping it to `<servlet-class>` map it to `<jsp-file>`